# How can I use React Native Table component for dynamic data?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-data-table-component

I did research to see some good table layout packages and I only got a react-native-table-component package but I have the following issues, can anyone please suggest any other library or solution for the following issues.

1. Actually I have some users data in JSON and want to have a loop where I can display some of the data under each table heading, I don't want to prepare data array first in sequence with header then placing the whole array in table as it works in table-component library.

**Example:** 
I have active/inactive users list and I want to add a condition on ID column if user is active create `href` tag else no `href`. how I will do this?

2. What is `flexarray` in table-component, I see the example `flexArr={[1, 2, 1, 1]}` but don't know what does this mean?

I am newbie to react-native please help me.